How to extract data from a map based on pattern
I have a map like this (jpg image):

and the corresponding patterns:

I want to create polygons (in a .shp file) based on the patterns.
The goal is to overlay a polygon and see which patterns fall in that overlayed polygon.
I've tried some things using opencv but without good results.
Is there any way to do something like this even approximately? Either in qgis or using pure python or some other software?

ask the author for their source data? -- that's texture analysis. if you're lucky, each texture's "background" is a unique color. then you can just work with that. if not... it's gonna get more complex. -- do you have better quality images?

K1 and K3 look almost identical, except for the ratio of circles to dots. that's terrible.

If the image is georeferenced and large enough it might be worth training a neural network to segment the image, eg. with orthoseg. But as it is a jpeg image and not a geotiff this is probably not the case...

@Christoph Rackwitz Sadly I have no clue who the author and no way to find them. I don't have a better quality image either this is straight from the source I have. And yes K1 and K3 are almost identical, I can only see usable difference in a good display and even then as you said only the ratio of the circles help. It's terrible indeed, hence my quest to digitize it. Also thanks for the term "texture analysis" it helps my search.

@Pieter the image is not georeferenced, I do have a very large data set tho containing multiple jpgs

a dumb little CNN should be able to do this. you'll have to iterate though, because you have basically no training data. the little legend would have to serve as a start. if you're lucky, that's barely enough to get the model started so it can identify easy regions in your actual data, that you can then manually verify and add to your training set. this is not how ML is "conventionally" done, but it's reasonable. if you have more data you can provide, preferably not recompressed (jpeg is lossy) but as close to source as possible... that might give someone a better basis for getting this done
